# can not understand average age caculating

Tags: python, append, average

I am a beginner to python. I am reading the following code:

```
people = [ [ 'John', 42 ], [ 'James', 36 ], [ 'Sue', 38 ] ]  
ages = [] 
for person in people:     
     age = person[1]     
     ages.append(age)  

avg_age = sum(ages) / len(people)
print "Average age:", avg_age
```

Questions:

1. what does `ages =[ ]` mean?
2. What does `age = people[1]` mean?
3. what does `ages.append(age)` mean?

Comment: 1. Assignment 2. Indexing 3. `append` method call on `ages` list.

Comment: 1. Creates an empty list named `ages` for storing ages in 2. Takes second element of a tuple and assigns to age 3. Appends an age to the `ages` list

Answer (score 0):

You might find it makes more sense if you expand the sublists in `people` directly:

```
people = [ [ 'John', 42 ], [ 'James', 36 ], [ 'Sue', 38 ] ]  
ages = [] 
for person, age in people:  
     ages.append(age)  

avg_age = sum(ages) / len(people)
print "Average age:", avg_age
```

And you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
people = [ [ 'John', 42 ], [ 'James', 36 ], [ 'Sue', 38 ] ]  
ages = [age for person, age in people] 

avg_age = sum(ages) / len(people)
print "Average age:", avg_age
```

Since you are not using `person` in your list comprehension, you can explicitly omit it:

```
people = [ [ 'John', 42 ], [ 'James', 36 ], [ 'Sue', 38 ] ]  
ages = [age for _, age in people] 

avg_age = sum(ages) / len(people)
print "Average age:", avg_age
```

Lastly, you will get a better average if you make one of your elements floating point. Here is one way:

```
people = [ [ 'John', 42 ], [ 'James', 36 ], [ 'Sue', 38 ] ]  
ages = [age for _, age in people] 

avg_age = sum(ages) / float(len(people))
print "Average age:", avg_age
```

Here is another:

```
people = [ [ 'John', 42 ], [ 'James', 36 ], [ 'Sue', 38 ] ]  
ages = [float(age) for _, age in people] 

avg_age = sum(ages) / len(people)
print "Average age:", avg_age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ages=[]
```

means you have created an empty list named ages. The list has no elements in it.

```
age=person[1]
```

is an assignment where you assign the value of the first element in person to ages.

```
ages.append(age)
```

appends the value age into the ages list.
Now when you print the list ages, you can see the value in age is appended to it.

```
ages=[]
ages.append(3)
ages.append(4)
print ages
```

will produce an output of

```
[3,4]
```

Comment: Thanks! but for "age = person[1]", I understand "ages.append(age)" " meaning "42" is appended to ages. So how can this code get the sum (ages) as "42 + 36 +38"?

Comment: After you have appended your age values in the ages list, it is not an empty list anymore.
`ages=[42,36,38]` is the now the list with the age values you have appended. `sum(ages)` takes every value form the list ages and adds it until the list reaches its end. You can also write it using a for loop as
`sum_of_ages=0
for value in ages:
 sum_of_ages+=value
printsum_of_ages`
will print the total of 42+36+38 which is `116`
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

what does ages =[ ] mean? 
It is an empty list that needs to be created before you can insert values.

What does age = people[1] mean? 
It means only the first placeholder in the dictionary needs to be read.

what does ages.append(age) mean?
It means put the age value of each dictionary entry into the ages list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ages =[ ] # creating an empty list
    age = people[1] # is assigning the value of first element of your list(people)
    ages.append(age) # you are adding the value of age to your second list (ages)
```

I suggest you go over the basic tutorials of python which have examples, so you can practice yourself and play around with lists to understand how its different methods behave.